# Порт занят но не удаётся найти работающий на нём процесс Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, port

При старте системы, если на +- **первой** минуте не включить какой-нибудь сервер на порту **3000**, то он чем-то занимается.

Например: пытаюсь запустить [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), подождав какое-то время после запуска системы

```
$ react-scripts start
Something is already running on port 3000.
```

Если это сделать **сразу после запуска** системы, то всё успешно запустится

Проблема в том, что прошерстив весь гугл, такой проблемы замечено не было. По крайней мере всем помогал `netstat`, но у меня он выдаёт ничего :(

```
$ netstat -aon | findstr "3000"
```

В итоге приходится каждый раз перезагружать систему, что не очень удобно

Мои спеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `UAC`, `Defender`, `Kaspersky`?

Comment: @donRumata `UAC` не высвечивается, `Defender` отключен, других антивирусов не имею

Answer (score 1):

Инструкция годная для Win7 дается из предположения, что аналогичный функционал есть у Win10. Прошу оставить комментарий, если опробуете инструкцию.

С помощью редактора групповой политики нужно активировать аудит.

1. Конфигурация компьютера **->** Конфигурация Windows **->** Локальные политики **->** Политика аудита
2. Включить **Аудит доступа к объектам**, параметры: как **Успех**, так и **Отказ**
3. Перегрузить компьютер

В журнале аудита можно увидеть следующую запись (при запуске соответствующего процесса):

```
Платформа фильтрации Windows разрешила подключение.

Сведения о приложении:
    Идентификатор процесса:     4396
    Имя приложения: \device\harddiskvolume1\program\server.exe

Сведения о сети:
    Направление:        Исходящие
    Адрес источника:        127.0.0.1
    Порт источника:     65030
    Адрес назначения:   127.0.0.1
    Порт назначения:        5581
    Протокол:       6

Сведения о фильтре:
    Код выполнения фильтра: 0
    Имя уровня:     Подключить
    Код выполнения уровня:  48
```

Как понятно из содержимого, в записях журнала "**Безопасность**" можно найти и процесс, и адрес используемого порта.

Приведу пример скрипта Powershell для поиска записей журнала "Безопасность" о приложениях, использующих требуемый порт, за последние 15 минут.

Сделан на базе **готового кода** [1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/)  и выводит найденные сведения в консоль.
Поиск осуществляется по EventId = 5156.
Естественно, нужны права Администратора при обращении к журналу "Безопасность".

```
#Request event log records with 15 minutes old
$Events = Get-WinEvent  -LogName "Security" -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=5156 and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 900000]]]"


ForEach ($Event in $Events) {            
    # Convert the event to XML            
    $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()            
    # Iterate through each one of the XML message properties            
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data.Count; $i++) {            

        $name=$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].name
        if ($name -match "Application") {
            $App=$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'
            $SourceAddress=""
            $DestPort=""                
            }

        if ($name -match "SourceAddress") {$SourceAddress=$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'}

        if ($name -match "DestPort") {
            $DestPort=$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'
            if ($DestPort  -match "3000") {
                Write-Output  $App
                Write-Output  $SourceAddress
                Write-Output  $DestPort
                Write-Output  $Event.TimeCreated
                Write-Output  "======"  
                }
            }   


    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Есть ли способ понять **какой именно процесс** занимает соотвествующий порт? Событий происходит достаточно много. Я там вижу только кнопку `Find`  где одно текстовое поле. Попробуй туда вбить `3000`

Comment: Для фильтрации журнала событий существуют различные скрипты, в основном Powershell (Get-EventLog)

Comment: К сожалению ни скрипт ничего не выдал, ни в журнале ничего не нашлось. Один раз я только поймал в приложении CurrPorts подключение на 3000 порт, и то это был не процесс а Unknown с каким-то ipшником Microsoft

Comment: Рекомендую проверить также события c EventId=5154. Возможно следует проверить и порт источника, то бишь поменять **DestPort** на **SourcePort**.

Comment: Оба варианта, к сожалению, ничего не дали

Comment: Ну ищите ещё события, возможно, - в Win10 у них иной EventId. Также воспользуйтесь ProcessMonitor, поможет и Tcpvcon (Tcpview).